# PHP 5.2 alternative syntax for recaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have the following server-side recpatcha code that works fine in PHP 5.3 and later:

```
require_once("Captcha/autoload.php");
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha("my_secret_key");
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"], $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
    die("Google reCaptcha believes you are a BOT: <b>" . $resp->getErrorCodes()[0] . ".</b> Please go back and prove you're a human.");
}
```

But I have one client who is still running PHP 5.2.17 and she isn't in a position to upgrade her server right now. The following line breaks in her version of PHP:

```
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha("my_secret_key");
```

Is there an alternative syntax that will work in older versions of PHP?

Comment: "But I have one client who is still running PHP 5.2.17 and she isn't in a position to upgrade her server right now."  — The last security update for that version of PHP was on 6 Jan 2011! They **need** to get into a position to upgrade it immediately!

Comment: You need to rewrite everything without namespaces (since those weren't introduced in PHP until 5.3 so yes, 5.2 is _that_ old). It will most likely take longer and cost more than upgrading the server, which you need to do ASAP anyway.

Comment: Magnus: are you saying it's not a simple code change in what I posted, but even the linked captcha libs would break?

Comment: Yes that's what Magnus is saying. And how in the world is your client "not in a position" to upgrade. As pointed out, they've had 9 years to get round to it. That's a very long time to ignore a security update. Could easily be considered negligence of the security of the data they hold.

Comment: @ADyson to be fair, it took Apple 10 years to agknowledge TLS 1.2 as a valid communications protocol between iPhone products and email servers so...... it's stupid, but it's not inconcievable.

Comment: Why bother trying to solve a captcha when you can use one of [literally dozens of unauthenticated RCE vulnerabilities against ancient, unpatched PHP](https://www.cvedetails.com/version/106044/PHP-PHP-5.2.17.html)? You don't even need to have "bad code", just a specifically-formatted request. IMHO you should consider that entire server compromised several times over, as there's no way it's survived 9+ years without being picked up by scans.

Comment: One approach here might be to use a very old version of the library - you can lock onto a specific numbered version if you want. Also you _might_ be able to run this code as a microservice, on another server. I doubt a spoonfeed answer would be available though - it would require some engineering persistence on your side.

Comment: I agree with the other comments - to the degree you need to pressure your client to upgrade. Perhaps they are putting up with the security risk because you do.